# Apache 2.4: How to log POST data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, apache2, amazon-linux-2

I have my LAMP application hosted on AWS EC2 Linux 2 instance. I can see requests logs in /var/log/httpd/access_log but there is no POST data there. I could figure out that I can use mod_dumpio or mod_security but I cannot get it to work.

I am new to both Apache and Linux therefore I need help with step-by-step instructions on how to get it done.

I have tried to use the a2enmod command but it doesn't seem to work on my version of linux.

Any help is really appreciated as I am unable to do it on my own.

Comment: Quite a few options at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache, but we're not going to write up instructions for you. `a2enmod` is a Ubuntu/Debian shortcut; all it does is enable the module in the Apache config.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have tried everything from that post. I modified configuration. But I couldn't restart Apache. It gave me error. Please Help, I am stuck for 2 days.

Comment: You need to tell us **what the error says** if we're to have any hope of guiding you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache

Steps to log HTTP request body in Apache:

1. Enable dumpio module for Apache.
2. Set the LogLevel to dumpio:trace7 and DumpIOInput On.
3. Restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

See also:

- [mod_dumpio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html)
- [Guide](https://www.simplified.guide/apache/log-post)

Comment: How exactly to perform these 3 steps. I have no clue. I tried the thing in Guide based on what I could make of it. I modified configuration file but Apache didn't restart and threw error.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had the wrong LogLevel, yours is the correct one.